# Error en un bucle for en jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este Script de supersize

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){

$.supersized({

// Functionality
slideshow : 1,  // Slideshow on/off
autoplay    :   1,  // Slideshow starts playing automatically
start_slide : 1,    // Start slide (0 is random)
stop_loop   :   0,  // Pauses slideshow on last slide
random  : 0,    // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
slide_interval : 3000,  // Length between transitions
transition : 6, // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
transition_speed    :   1000,   // Speed of transition
new_window  :   1,  // Image links open in new window/tab
pause_hover : 0,    // Pause slideshow on hover
keyboard_nav : 1,   // Keyboard navigation on/off
performance :   1,  // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
image_protect   :   1,  // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

// Size & Position  
min_width   : 0,    // Min width allowed (in pixels)
min_height  : 0,    // Min height allowed (in pixels)
vertical_center : 1,    // Vertically center background
horizontal_center : 1,  // Horizontally center background
fit_always  :   1,  // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
fit_portrait : 1,   // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
fit_landscape   : 1,    // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

// Components   
slide_links :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
thumb_links :   1,  // Individual thumb links for each slide
thumbnail_navigation : 0,   // Thumbnail navigation


slides : // Slideshow Images

//bucle aqui-------------------------->

for(var i=1;i<=11;i++){

[{image : './thumbs/'+[i]+'.jpg', title : 'hola', thumb :'./thumbs/miniatura/'+[i]+'.jpg', url : ''}],


}



// Theme Options    
progress_bar    :   2,  // Timer for each slide 
mouse_scrub :   0

});
});
```

Quiero que me cargue un numero de imagenes desde 1 hasta 11 pero me da error de sintaxis. A lo mejor en esta funcion no se puede poner este `for`.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes poner una instrucción for en la definición de un objeto. Deberías construir el array fuera de la definición:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

    var slides = [];
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
        slides.push({
            image: './thumbs/' + [i] + '.jpg',
            title: 'hola',
            thumb: './thumbs/miniatura/' + [i] + '.jpg',
            url: ''
        });
    }

    $.supersized({
        // Functionality
        slideshow: 1, // Slideshow on/off
        autoplay: 1, // Slideshow starts playing automatically
        start_slide: 1, // Start slide (0 is random)
        stop_loop: 0, // Pauses slideshow on last slide
        random: 0, // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
        slide_interval: 3000, // Length between transitions
        transition: 6,
        // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed: 1000, // Speed of transition
        new_window: 1, // Image links open in new window/tab
        pause_hover: 0, // Pause slideshow on hover
        keyboard_nav: 1, // Keyboard navigation on/off
        performance: 1,
        // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
        image_protect: 1, // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

        // Size & Position  
        min_width: 0, // Min width allowed (in pixels)
        min_height: 0, // Min height allowed (in pixels)
        vertical_center: 1, // Vertically center background
        horizontal_center: 1, // Horizontally center background
        fit_always: 1, // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
        fit_portrait: 1, // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
        fit_landscape: 1, // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

        // Components   
        slide_links: 'blank', // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
        thumb_links: 1, // Individual thumb links for each slide
        thumbnail_navigation: 0, // Thumbnail navigation

        slides: slides,// Slideshow Images

        // Theme Options    
        progress_bar : 2, // Timer for each slide 
        mouse_scrub: 0
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.supersized/3.2.7/core/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.... la torpeza de uno es salvada por alguien brillante...;-)